# jQuery not recognising change of class on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK so I made a custom function which I can then call using a div's class.

I target the class 'back' then this function is applied which enlarges and moves the div. Once this animation is complete, I remove the class 'back' and add the class 'front'.

I have another function which is looking for a click on the element with class 'front', however when I click this element, which only has the class 'front' and not 'back' it is still triggering the first function.

How can this be if it doesn't have that class anymore?

Here is my code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    (function ($) {
        $.fn.expand = function () {

            var wide = this.css('width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') * 10;
            var high = this.css('height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') * 10;
            var marg = -(wide / 2);
            $(this).removeClass('back');
            $(this).animate({
                'width': wide,
                'height': high,
                'margin-left': marg,
                'bottom': '0'
            }, 3000, 'easeInOutCubic', function () {
                $(this).addClass('front');
            });

        };
    })(jQuery);

    $('.back').click(function () {
        $(this).expand();
        $('.wall').animate({
            'bottom': '+=10px'
        }, 3000, 'easeInOutCubic');
    });

    $('.front').click(function () {
        $('.wall').animate({
            'bottom': '-=100px'
        }, 300);
        $('.floor').animate({
            'bottom': '-=100px'
        }, 300);
    });
}); // JavaScript Document
```

...and the current file here.. http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/chinahurdles/index.html

Comment: Q: Why are you nesting two styles of DOM-ready handler? The inner one is not even using the jQuery of the outer one.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. It was a very early attempt at a custom function/plugin so there may well be superfluous code there. If you could give me an idea of what to get rid of I'd be more than happy to know. Thanks

Comment: Added to answer below. Let me know if that is not enough information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by statically attaching event handlers to elements with classes of .back and .front *at load time*. The handers stay attached to those specific elements,  even if you change the classes.

As the classes change dynamically, use delegated event handlers *attached to a non-changing ancestor element (`document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient)*.

```
$(document).on('click', '.back', function() {
    $(this).expand();
    $('.wall').animate({'bottom':'+=10px'}, 3000, 'easeInOutCubic');
});

$(document).on('click', '.front', function() {
    $('.wall').animate({'bottom':'-=100px'}, 300);
    $('.floor').animate({'bottom':'-=100px'}, 300);
});
```

Delegated events work by listening for an event to bubble up to the targeted ancestor element (in this case `document`), *then* they apply the jQuery selector *to only the elements in the bubble chain*, *then* it applies the function to any matching elements *that actually caused the event*.

Basically they evaluate the selector at *event time*, not *when the event was registered*, so work with dynamically changed/added content.

**Side note:**

You have nested two DOM ready handlers. `$(function ($) {` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(` with a locally scoped `$`. Although nesting DOM ready handlers is harmless, it is a waste (as the inner one fires immediately)

Use either just this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.expand = function () {
```

or

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.expand = function () {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that browser reads all your handlers and applies its ones page is loaded.
So it's wrong to set handler to class. Class is only specifier to find specific DOM element

I suggest you to use next solution
Use **on** event on any parent element and apply your handler to it

```
$(document).on('click', '.front', function() {
});

$(document).on('click', '.back', function() {
});
```

So each time your click has fired on element it propagates to element with handler, and will search to call exactly callback with specific selector (class .back or .front)

Comment: Do not use `body` as the default for delegated events. Use `document` (which has the added benefit of existing even before the DOM is loaded). There is a bug to do with page styling that means `body` may not get delegated mouse events.

Comment: OK, its just for example to show the idea. I will change my code

Answer (score 0):

You have added a listener to the DOM element. Changing the elements classes won't remove the listeners you have already attached. The closest solution to what you have tried to do with classes would be something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    (function($){
        $.fn.expand = function() {

            var wide = this.css('width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '')*10;
            var high = this.css('height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '')*10;

            var marg = - ( wide / 2 );

            $(this).unbind("click");
            $(this).animate({'width' : wide ,'height': high, 'margin-left': marg, 'bottom':'0' }, 3000, 'easeInOutCubic', function() {
                $(this).click(frontFunction);
            });

        };

        $('.back').click(backFunction);
    })(jQuery);

    var backFunction = function() {
        $(this).expand();
        $('.wall').animate({'bottom':'+=10px'}, 3000, 'easeInOutCubic');
    };

    var frontFunction = function() {
        $('.wall').animate({'bottom':'-=100px'}, 300);
        $('.floor').animate({'bottom':'-=100px'}, 300);
    };


});
```

Comment: That is indeed the problem... but what is your solution/answer? :)

Comment: Rather than toggle static handlers on/off, why not simply use delegated events (see either of the other answers)?

Comment: It seemed like what he tried to do. I assume that it is also faster.

Comment: Delegated event handlers are the same speed to connect if single elements (like here), and faster to connect if there were multiple matches. The speed at click time does not matter as you cannot click fast enough to ever notice the added overhead (unless you can click 50,000 times per second) :).

Comment: Ok, nice. It also seems event delegation saves memory :P

Comment: It only saves a trivial amount of memory. As it only connects the handler to a single element's event list.