# jQuery doesn't recognise that the class changed, although the Browser does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying out to create a Dropdown-menu with jQuery. I have 3 Sub-folders with 3 sub-sub-folders each (correct me if this is the wrong term). Depending on wether the Sub-folder is collapsed (Sub-subs invisible) or expanded (Sub-subs visible) there´s a little arrow pointing downwards when expanded and to the right when collapsed. I´m a Newbie and don´t want to use many external scripts, so I remove the `Subshown_arrow` Class and add the Subhidden_arrow Class when clicked (or the other way).

```
<a href="#"> <img id="arrow" class="Subshown_arrow" /> Sub-forum 1 </a>
            <li class="sub-sub"> <a href="#"> Sub-sub-forum 1 <li>
            <li class="sub-sub"> <a href="#"> Sub-sub-forum 2 <li>
            <li class="sub-sub"> <a href="#"> Sub-sub-forum 3 <li>
```

I removed the scr here ^, normally it´s there.

```
var main = function() {


$(".Subshown_arrow").click(function() {
    alert("Subshown_arrow clicked!");
    $(this).removeClass("Subshown_arrow").addClass("Subhidden_arrow");
});

$(".Subhidden_arrow").click(function() {
    alert("Subhidden_arrow clicked!");
    $(this).removeClass("Subhidden_arrow").addClass("Subshown_arrow");
});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

However, when I click the Arrow for the first time, it rotates as expected. But when I click it another time, jQuery reacts as if it was clicked for the first time. The alerts print out "Subshown_arrow clicked!" every time.

But when I tried it out in the Browser and used Chrome´s built-in tools to view the Code, the Class changed. That means that changing the Class works, but my jQuery script ignores it.

What have i done wrong? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: img without src what exactly you are doing?

Comment: `<li>` without `<ul>`, `<a>` without closing tag. You sgould really improve your html (even though this is not what's causing your problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery not recognising change of class on element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073470/jquery-not-recognising-change-of-class-on-element)

Comment: @Jai I said that i removed the src here, but ofc it´s normally there                   "I removed the scr here ^, normally it´s there." Directly under the html stuff.

Comment: @mmgross That´s just a part of the source, in the complete document all tags are closed correctly.                                                                                                                                       2.  Nope, no duplicate. I am not the author of the other Question.

Comment: @J.R i get it now. an answer is posted though. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35936869/1059101

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has already been solved thousands of times, you are binding to .Subhidden_arrow and .Subshown_arrow classes when the first doesn't exist yet. You need to bind the events differently:

$('body').on('click', '.Subhidden_arrow', function ( e ) {});

This will work also on dynamically created (changed) elements.

Comment: really? that is one of the other issues.

Comment: the body tag is just an example of parent which is static in the page, you may want to use the first parent that is always there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.on` it will work when classes changes as new handler will be assigned to it. but when you use `.click` it is assigend to the object that had the matching class at first and although the class has changed but still the old handler is assigned to it.

```
var main = function() {


$("body").on("click",".Subshown_arrow",function() {
    alert("Subshown_arrow clicked!");
    $(this).removeClass("Subshown_arrow").addClass("Subhidden_arrow");
});

$("body").on("click","Subhidden_arrow",function() {
    alert("Subhidden_arrow clicked!");
    $(this).removeClass("Subhidden_arrow").addClass("Subshown_arrow");
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `img` without any `src` and if you have more images then i would mention to *not to use same ids*.

So, what you can do is give a common class name to the element:

```
 <img class="arrow Subshown_arrow" />
 <!----------^^^^^-------like this one---->
```

Now you can use the class `arrow` to bind the click event and you can use `toggleClass()` method to change the classes:

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("Subshown_arrow Subhidden_arrow");
});
```

Comment: So I can assign multiple Classes directly to one element? Nice, I didn´t knew that. That was the only reason why I used an ID.

Comment: IMHO, that is how we should do when we work with a collection, as this is by far follow DRY fundamentals, less code with multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the problem is that the click is bound on document load, at which time there are no elements with a class `subhidden_arrow`. This can indeed be solved by using a parent elements click and a filter on the class using (`on`). However, the original bound click event can also be reused to toggle the classes:

```
$(".Subshown_arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("Subshown_arrow").toggleClass("Subhidden_arrow");
});
```

The click is bound to the element on load and reacts on both 'states', regardless of which class it holds then.

An example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rggckhcg/) with a slight alteration to make the containing anchor react to the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Better way

```
var main = function() {

$("#arrow").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("Subshown_arrow").toggleClass("Subhidden_arrow"); 
});

};

$(document).ready(main);
```